# knockout.js validation on observableArray to require all items (no empty fields)

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

I have written the following example of using knockout.

HTML

```
<script id="customMessageTemplate" type="text/html">
    <em class="customMessage" data-bind='validationMessage: field'></em>
</script>
<fieldset>
    <legend>User: <span data-bind='text: errors().length'></span> errors</legend>
    <label>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName'/></label>
    <label>Last name: <input data-bind='value: lastName'/></label>    

    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Value</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: captcha">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: value" type="test" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" data-bind='click: submit'>Submit</button>
```

Knockout

```
ko.validation.rules.pattern.message = 'Invalid.';


ko.validation.configure({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: true,
    parseInputAttributes: true,
    messageTemplate: null
});


var captcha = function (val) {
    return val == 11;
};

var mustEqual = function (val, other) {
    return val == other();
};

var viewModel = {
    firstName: ko.observable().extend({ required: true }),
    lastName: ko.observable().extend({ required: true }),
    captcha: ko.observableArray([{value: "test"}]),


    submit: function () {
        if (viewModel.errors().length == 0) {
            alert('Thank you.');
        } else {
            alert('Please check your submission.');
            viewModel.errors.showAllMessages();
        }
    }
};


viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

What should I add to observableArray to require all items in this array the same way like usual observable object reffrering to input fields FirstName and LastName in presented example?

Comment: What do mean by *to require all items in this array*?

Comment: @adiga I don't want to leave empty fields.

Comment: Add a required validation to `value` similar to `firstName`?

Comment: @adiga sorry for misunderstanding, the observable object like firstName has attribute required and validation works, how about observableArray Should I add something for this array to check each item inside if not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are expecting. If you want to add validation to each object of an `observableArray`, you can do something like this:

Create a `captchaViewModel` function and add the `required` validation to the `value` property

```
var captchaViewModel = function(val) {
  this.value = ko.observable(val).extend({
    required: true
  });
 // other properties if any
}
```

Then change your `viewModel` to:

```
var viewModel = {
  firstName: ko.observable().extend({ required: true }),
  lastName: ko.observable().extend({ required: true }),
  captcha: ko.observableArray([new captchaViewModel("test")]),

  submit: function() {
    if (viewModel.errors().length == 0) {
      alert('Thank you.');
    } else {
      alert('Please check your submission.');
      viewModel.errors.showAllMessages();
    }
  }
};
```

You also need to add `grouping` property to the [configuration](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration) and set `deep: true`.

```
ko.validation.configure({
   .......
   .......
  // "deep" indicates whether to walk the ViewModel (or object) recursively, 
  // or only walk first-level properties
  grouping: { deep: true }
});
```

[Here's a fiddle for testing](https://jsfiddle.net/29sg0jd3/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add your [custom validation rule](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Custom-Validation-Rules) like so:

```
ko.validation.rules['noEmptyValues'] = {
    validator: function (arr) {
        return arr.every(function(v) {
          return v && v.value; // TODO: confirm this is the test condition
        });
    },
    message: "Array contains empty items"
};

// Some place else:
var arrayThatCannotContainEmptyValues = ko.observableArray([])
  .extend({ noEmptyValues: true });
```

It's not exactly clear what the test should be at the `// TODO` line, but I'm sure you can figure it out.

Note that this only works when you're modifying the actual array. Since `value` isn't observable, it won't trigger an update in the example above.